# How to solve error while creating new HTML file

Tags: html, css

On Atom whenever I try to create a HTML or CSS, it shows "Uncaught TypeError: this.action.disposalAction is not a function".
Then my file doesn't work.
Please help me to solve the problem. [Atom File making error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJVAr.png)

Comment: Maybe just not use the `autoclose` package?

Comment: There is an error in your package, try to remove that package named autoclose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Atom | Preferences** and select **Packages** from the list at the left.

Scroll down to find the ***autoclose***  package listed under Packages, or type “autoclose” into the search box.
Click the Disable button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing that Type Error
You just go to that specific atom folder and select packages and check if there is ***autoclose-html*** folder is there or not

if it's there just delete it and download it and disable it so by doing that you won't able to see that error again..